# React Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just start a basic React project and in my home.js I can see this warning.
Please note that I've added the key as unique key in home.js but still the error is there. I have checked other posts from the community, but I was not able to spot the error, hence asking for help!

If you could help, I would owe you a lot!

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `home`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at small
    at Homepage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:613:63)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39951:5)
    at div
    at ApolloProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:55884:19)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39884:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39364:5)
    at App
```

Please find bellow my home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'

const REVIEWS = gql`
  query GetReviews {
    reviews {
        data{
            id
            attributes{
              title
              rating
              body
              categories{
                data{
                  attributes
                  {
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
`
export default function Homepage() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(REVIEWS)

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>

    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div>
            {data.reviews.data.map(review => (
                <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                    <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                    <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>

                    {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                        <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                    ))}

                    <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... </p>
                    <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read more</Link>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client"

// page & layout imports
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage'
import ReviewDetails from './pages/ReviewDetails'
import Category from './pages/Category'
import SiteHeader from "./components/SiteHeader"

// apollo client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <div className="App">
            <SiteHeader />
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={ <Homepage />}>

              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/details/:id" element={<ReviewDetails />}>

              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/category/:id" element={<Category />}>

              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: I guess not all your category ids are unique or c.id is not defined? Try logging them to see more?

Comment: I agree with @AndreasJagiella, so you can generate a random key on your own using other packages like UUIDjs. It will guarantee that you are going to have a unique because you are controlling the unique on your side, not on the back-end and API side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! You pointed me in the right direction! I was missing the `id` in gql statement

```
 query GetReviews {
    reviews {
        data{
            id
            attributes{
              title
              rating
              body
              categories{
                data{
                  id
                  attributes
                  {
                    name
                  }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to react as well. Does `review.id` exist and is it unique? Please see if it is review._id or something like that.

if `review.id` doesn't exist or if it is not unique. Then this is one other way to fix this.

```
 {data.reviews.data.map((review, i) => ( 
 <div key={i} className="review-card"> // ->made only this change

 <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                    <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>

                    {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                        <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                    ))}

                    <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... 
                     </p>
                    <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read 
                  more</Link>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: in the error stacktrace you can see that it is the <small> thats causing the problem. Also what you are doing does not make sense. When you remove the first item of the review list, all items would get different keys. This is not what keys are used for in react. "Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed." https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html